# can't take bug report android 4.1

Tags: android, debugging

On an Android 4.1.2, under Developer Options, there's an item called "take bug report". It says it will collect logs and allow to send an email. It does absolutely nothing.

How do I get it to work?

I also remember that on some versions of Android you would just press a combination of buttons to do the same, but I can't figure out which buttons it was.

I just need to have a customer be able to collect the full logs and send them to me.

Comment: Are you trying to catch crashes in your app? It's rare that bug reports get sent anyway, I coded my own one in so I always get an email without fail.

Comment: I just want to collect the log. The same that I would see in logcat if the device was connected to adb. The same that in older versions of Android I would collect with applications like LogCollector, which has become impossible after 4.something. Then there was a combination of buttons (which was difficult as hell to reproduce) which would generate a report (which included the recent contents of log) and would allow you to send e.g. via email. Now there's this "Take bug report" option in Developer Options, which is supposed to do the same, isn't it? but it simply does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's rare that bug reports get sent"? What "your own" did you code? I don't need something that automagically sends me anything. I need a manual action so that I tell my client: "press button Whatever / go to menu Whatever and email me the result".

Comment: Hi Matteo, "Take bug reports" never works well in my opinion and never gives meaningful information for anything other than system apps. The code I wrote is always watching for crashes in your app, and when it notices the crash, it emails me with the exception code (What you would see in the logcat). You can then see where your app crashes and the exception information. If this is what you want then I will write the code in an answer for you.

Comment: I appreciate but that is not the answer I'm looking for. I don't want the app to automatically email me when it crashes. I want to be able to retrieve the logcat when I (or the user) want. Also, the app will only be able to see its own logs. What I need is to be able to do what LogCollector used to do before the more restrictive permission policies were introduced which render it unable to see any log. Also, I wonder why the "Take bug report" option does absolutely nothing. A combination of buttons like volume up+down+power used to do the job on some android version, but no more.